# How may I send the content of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How may I send the content of the `description` textarea?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
   <form action="foo?idA=140" id="formu" method="post">    
      <div class="modal fade" id="rpopup" hidden>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="titred"><small>Veuillez décrire brièvement ce que vous avez fait</small></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea id="description" cols="90" rows="5" maxlength="200" style="border:0px;" autofocus required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="submitd">Valider</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script>
        $('#re').on('click', function (e) {
            $('#rpopup').modal('show');
        });
        $("#submitd").click(function () {
            $("#formu").submit();
        });
    </script>
```

When I fill that and I send it I get an `undefined` value. How do I to deal with this, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $("#re") Where is your html element with the id "re"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give a [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-name) to the [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea), then the contents of the textarea will be sent as a request params along with any other form data. You can access it in the server from the request object using the name you gave to the textarea

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" cols="90" rows="5" maxlength="200" style="border:0px;" autofocus required></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

While using form to submit data, you have to use `name` attribute for all input fields.

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" cols="90" rows="5" maxlength="200" style="border:0px;" autofocus required></textarea>
```

Then, you can access this value in the action page using the name of the textarea,

```
$_POST['description'];
```